# How could i fix TypeError when sending a dm to a person?

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to make a DM command that sends the message and the author provided with it.
But, I've been getting this error: `TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

This is the code I have right now:

```py
@client.command()
async def sendadm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    if ctx.message.author.id == owner_discord_id:
        message = message or ""
        await user.send(message)
    else:
        await user.send(message, "\n\nSent by {ctx.author}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [`User.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.send) method is an instance method, so `self` will be implicitly passed, hence your error saying that 3 positional arguments were given. (The first positional argument is `self`. The optional second positional argument is `content`.) The main issue is that you are trying to pass two different values to the positional argument `content`.

It seems that you are trying to combine the message string and `"\n\nSent by {ctx.author}"`, so see the below "corrected" code.

---

```py
@client.command()
async def sendadm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    if ctx.message.author.id == owner_discord_id:
        message = message or ""
        await user.send(message)
    else:
        await user.send(f"{message}\n\nSent by {ctx.author}")
```